# OCJP-“it is legal to serialize object of a type that has a supertype that does not implement java.io.Serialazable” is correct?

Tags: java, serialization

While looking for OCJP question, I saw a question(at [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pJbokOb47WDtRe9hX1C1Dgjjh2_8elZejGwzluHLrtA/mobilebasic?hl=en) question 5):
‘’’it is legal to serialize object of a type that has a supertype that does NOT implement java.io.Serialazable .’’’
Answer says it’s correct, but how can I serialize object of class that does NOT implement ‘’’Serializable’’’ class?
Isn’t it also strange that we can’t say it’s totally illegal because the class might implement ‘’’java.io.Serializable’’’ DIRECTLY?

Comment: _Every_ serializable class has a supertype that does not implement `Serializable`. If that made it unserializable, then no object would be serializable.

Comment: @khelwood But let’s say we got ‘’’class A{}’’’ and ‘’’class B extends A{}’’’. Class B “has a supertype that does NOT implement java.io.Serialazable”. So is it legal to serialize class B?

Comment: I think it means to say "having a supertype that does not implement `Serializable` does not forbid an object from being serialized"; not "having a supertype that does not implement `Serializable` *enables* an object to be serialized"

Comment: Am I thinking too strictly or not catching up what the question really wanted to say..?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

If a superclass is not serializable then subclass can still be serialized : Even though superclass doesn’t implements Serializable interface, we can serialize subclass object if subclass itself implements Serializable interface. So we can say that to serialize subclass object, superclass need not to be serializable.
But what happens with the instances of superclass during serialization in this case-

**Serialization**: At the time of serialization, if any instance variable is inheriting from non-serializable superclass, then JVM ignores original value of that instance variable and save default value to the file.

**De- Serialization**: At the time of de-serialization, if any non-serializable superclass is present, then JVM will execute instance control flow in the superclass. To execute instance control flow in a class, JVM will always invoke default(no-arg) constructor of that class. So every non-serializable superclass must necessarily contain default constructor, otherwise we will get runtime-exception.